# how can work with regExp in jQuery from getting class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get classname from click, and use RegExp to get text from class like `sort_alpha` ,`sort_date` to change `alpha`, `date` , but this is not work.
Thanks for helping!!!

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/myhk2009/7j4wstu7/

Comment: You can use `split` instead...like this `"sort_alpha".split('_')[1]` which will return `alpha`

Comment: Fiddle might be nice, but you should also include the relevant code into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#displayData').on('click', '.tb_data thead th', function(){
var className = $(this).attr('class').match(new RegExp(/sort_[\w]+/g));
            var str = className[0].replace(/^sort_/g,"");
            alert(str);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

.match method returns array of matches. So you should write it like this:

```
var className = this.className.match(/sort_[\w]+/g)[0];
```